# Debugging ASP.NET Timeout

Tags: asp.net

I need to debug an asp.net website following a timeout, i.e. via a breakpoint placed in the .aspx page that is specified as the loginURL setting in forms authentication config.

However, I understand that when debug="true" the site will not timeout ([link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2006/04/13/575364.aspx))

So how can I debug timeout scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are interested in finding out which part of the code is slow enough to cause the request to time out. If you step through it line-by-line in debug mode, you should be able to identify which line is causing the problem, even though the 'timeout' exception will not get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If time-outs are the problem, why not use the standard trace functionality in ASP.NET? Using the trace information enables you to determine where the most time is spent. This may help to identify the bottleneck.

See [here](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/tracefunctionality.aspx) for an example of tracing in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

re:

> "Thanks for the replies above, although rather than identifying what is causing the timeout, I need to actually cause a timeout and trace through code following the timeout.

A problem has been reported whereby following a timeout and logging back in to the site, some strange behaviour has been observed which I am trying to identify."

Perhaps there is no way to do this in debug mode then. Trace might be useful, or adding in lots of commands to log information to a file so you can later see what was happening.

One other thought: Are your users pressing the back button after getting the timeout error? In some situations this could lead to unexpected behaviour.